# Laravel. Model. Permission denied

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, model

for 2 days i cant solve this problem.

I created a new table "alarms", then i created a model "Alarm". If i try to get data from "alarms" table using "Alarm" model, laravel returns error "permission denied".

It happends if i try to use this model form api routes. If i try to get data from console, everything is ok.

Other models work fine and i dont see any difference between them and "Alarm".

May be someone solve this problem? I dont know what to do.

Thank you a lot for any comments!

P.S. text of error below:

`include(/var/www/www-root/data/www/api.poscare.ru/app/Models/Alarm.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: Please give permission to Models folder

Comment: you need to give read/write permission to the respected folder.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you a lot! Didnt think about folder!

Comment: @НикитаДмитриевичХорев: Can i make as answer of my comment?

Comment: Of course!  It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite permission to your model folder as a root:

```
chmod a+rwx model_folder -R
```